# Airflow passing 'ti' into a python method

Tags: python, airflow

Good evening,

In Airflow I have a task_group (tg1) that loops through a list and dynamically calls a python method which then generates a series of tasks. The issue that I am having is that I need to have access to Xcoms inside of the python method and I keep seeing error:

KeyError: "task_instance".  or "KeyError: "ti".   I have called it both ways to be sure.

Task Group Code:

```
    ...
    for partitions in partition_list:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='Refresh_Wrapper_{0}'.format(iteration),
            python_callable=refresh_task(task_id, partitions, dag, iteration),
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag
        )
    ...
```

Python Method Code:

```
     def refresh_task(task_group, data, dag, iteration, **context):
         foo = "baz{0}".format(str(iteration))
         bar = "Bar " + context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids=task_group.foo, key='return_value')
         .....
```

Comment: please add full traceback

Comment: KeyError: "task_instance". or "KeyError: "ti". I have called it both ways to be sure. Referencing the bar = line in the Python method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In The PythonOpertator you should put only the name of the function.
If you need to pass params to the function, use op_kwargs like the follow:

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='Refresh_Wrapper_{0}'.format(iteration),
            python_callable=refresh_task,
            op_kwargs={"task_id": task_id, "partitions": partitions, "dag": dag, "iteration": iteration},
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag
        )
```

also dag you can get from the context["dag_run"]

Comment: This is absolutely good advice. But even after a refactor im not getting the 'ti' in the python method so I cant access xcoms

Comment: you can use jinja template and send the value from outside the callable : op_kwargs={"reutrn_value": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_id', key='return_value') }}"}